# Error deploying to AWS through visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2013, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My co-worker is able to deploy our projects to AWS Elastic beanstalk fine. However I have issues on both my work machine and my home laptop. Both computers have the same error in AWS window pane.

I get a pop up as follows:

> Deployment of the website failed due to errors during build of the deployment archive,
>   check visual studio output window 'Build' and/ or 'Amazon Web Service' panes for more details.

Then in the amazon window pane I get a different error everytime I try to run the deployment.

Example 1:

> ...package build 'CopyPipelineFiles': error in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets' at (1413,5): Copying file Web.config to obj\AmazonDev\TransformWebConfig\original\Web.config failed. Could not find file 'Web.config'.

Example 2:

> ...package build 'TransformXml': error in 'C:\Users\Andrew\colony\colony-website\Colony.Web\Colony.Web.csproj' at (840,5): Could not open Transform file: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Andrew\colony\colony-website\Colony.Model\Web.AmazonDev.config'.

Seems to be a different error each time -- I'm not sure how to even begin to look for any issues.

Comment: Struggling with the same issue. Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776689/error-deploying-mvc4-project-cant-find-file-or-assembly

Comment: Are you using ReSharper perchance? Some users have experienced this error after an upgrade to ReSharper 8.2. Here is the issue with JetBrains: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-411186

Comment: Had same issue, suspended Resharper and worked, nice catch! Hope they patch Resharper soon.

Comment: @codeplay - I've edited your answer to surface this helpful information for other users, so if you undelete it I'll happily upvote too (can't do so while it is deleted still).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jim Flangagan's comment is the answer: ReSharper 8.2 is causing this problem. To resolve either disable resharper ( Tools>Options>ReSharper>General>Suspend Now) or upgrade Resharper.